# JSON-XML Converter Java library?

Tags: java, xml, json, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

Are there any good JSON to XML and Vice-versa java lib converters available, Which can convert the formats on the fly. On the fly means, if i give a JSON object (not .json file reader sorts) it should gimme back an xml document (and not .xml file) .

Tried XStream, but its giving me unwanted Element nodes which is not required in my xml.
The converter in Json.org was close, but it creates only Text/node based XML and NOT creating attribute based.

Eg: If my JSON data is :

```
{Order:{OrderLine:{ItemID:"1234"}},OrderNo:"4567"}
```

Output that i want is :

```
<Order OrderNo="4567"><OrderLine ItemID="1234"/></Order>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the **json-lib** library? http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/usage.html#xml

Comment: Hi Rod, Yup tried that too but even then it gives these unwanted nodes like <o> <e> etc. so couldnt go ahead with it.

Comment: Question, for any reason do you have the POJOs?, because your problem could be easily solved if you have them